# Insert into with subquery

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to rewrite the following without a subquery?

```
INSERT INTO ki_permissions_users (permission_id, user_id)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM ki_permissions WHERE name = 'permission_name' LIMIT 1) , '2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this.

```
INSERT INTO ki_permissions_users (permission_id, user_id)
SELECT id, '2' 
FROM ki_permissions 
WHERE name = 'permission_name' 
LIMIT 1
```

You can't get rid of subquery. You can only execute it beforehand and then construct appropriate `INSERT` statement. The choice is yours.